# Typescript field does not show up

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a typescript model named as Transaction, which extends a class called Serializable as follows:

```
export class Transaction extends Serializable {
    public BankAccountNo:             number;
    public ResponseID:                number;
    //more properties
    public ShowRateInverted:          boolean; //newly added property
    public RetMsg:                    string;
}

export class Serializable {
    fillFromJSON(jsonObj: any) {
        for (let propName in jsonObj) {
            this[propName] = jsonObj[propName]
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a new field called `ShowRateInverted`. This field does not show up in chrome tools however all other properties show up.Please see below:
[image]

I am debugging in chrome after api call is done and values are assigned to transaction object.

I have cleaned cache, restarted my machine to no avail.Would be great if someone can share some insight on this.

FYI: VSCode shows intellisense for 'ShowRateInverted' while typing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my API was not returning that `ShowRateInverted` , once I made it to return that.Everything was fine.